# How to use trailing return type with a templated class member

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

I'm trying to implement the following class:

```
template <typename Container>
class reverse_adaptor
{
public: // Construction
    reverse_adaptor(Container &container) :
        m_container(container)
    {}

public: // STL container static polymorphism
    auto begin() const -> decltype(m_container.rbegin())
    {
        return m_container.rbegin();
    }

    auto end() const -> decltype(m_container.rend())
    {
        return m_container.rend();
    }

private: // Members
    Container &m_container;
};
```

The reason I'm using the trailing return type is because I don't know if m_container will be const or not, so I let the compiler work it out for me. However, I'm getting the following compiler errors:

> /Users/mark/Blah/Stdx.h:77:40: No member named 'm_container' in
>   'stdx::reverse_adaptor > >'

I thought it might be related to the multi-stage pass of templated types, so changed it to read `decltype(this->m_container.rbegin())`, but that didn't work either.

How can I get this to work?

Example - http://ideone.com/ekVYlH

Comment: Meh, just wait a bit for decltype(auto) and don't bother ^^.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::declval` instead of using the member directly in the `decltype` expression? That should fix it. Not an answer as I don't know whether this is what the standard requires or an issue with your toolchain

Comment: `begin` and `end` need to know about `m_container`, it needs to be declared before them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *trailing-return-type* of a function is part of its “*signature*” (declaration), not of its “body” (definition), and as such, it only sees names that were *declared before*.

At the point where you declare your `begin` member function, `m_container` hasn't been declared yet. (Note that the issue is not specific to template classes.)

- You could move the declaration of `m_container` up in the class definition (but it forces you to put private members before public interface, which is contrary to common practice...).
- You can work-around with [`declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval): replace `m_container` with `std::declval<Container&>()` inside the `decltype`: http://ideone.com/aQ8Apa

(As said in the comments, in C++14 you'll be able to drop the trailing return type and just use `decltype(auto)` as the “normal” return type.)

---

*Addendum:* As for why you can use not-yet-declared members inside the in-class body of a member function but not in the trailing return type, it's because the following:

```
class Foo {
public:
    auto data() const -> decltype(m_data)
    {
        return m_data;
    }
private:
    SomeType m_data;
};
```

will be *<sub>[disclaimer: informal wording!]</sub>* kind of “rewritten by the compiler” into something equivalent to this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    inline auto data() const -> decltype(m_data); // declaration only
private:
    SomeType m_data;
};

// at this point, all members have been declared

inline auto Foo::data() const -> decltype(m_data) // definition
{
    return m_data;
}
```

where a name cannot be used before its declaration (which the first `decltype(m_data)` violates).

Comment: Great, thanks. I went for `std::declval<Container&>()` as the fix, as I hate having private class members / methods before public or protected ones.

Answer (score 2):

The name `m_container` has not been introduced at the point the functions are *declared*. Switch the order of declarations, and the code will work.

See working version [here](http://ideone.com/2bHm1C).